# how to get the image with largest size among all the images on the page

Tags: php, regex, image, url, loops

I am quite newbie to extract the different data from a given url.However,i found  the following code  to extract the images who  are greater in size  than the listted width  and height.

in this way,I am getting  2 or three images.

1. How can I automatically, get the one image of largest size?
2. if image size is given as it is mentiontioned in the the below loop,how to show only one image.?
3. the code is comparitivaly slow.it takes time to give output.how it can be more faster?
4. I just copied the code .if a little comments  are to be given on whts happening in this loop,then this will be much  in code understanding

   ```
       $string = $co->fetch_record ($url2);

       $image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
       preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
       $images_array = $img[1];
       ?>

       <div class="images">
           <?php
           $k = 0;
           for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof ($images_array); $i++) {
               if(@$images_array[$i]) {
                   if(@getimagesize (@$images_array[$i])) {
                       list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize (@$images_array[$i]);
                       if($width >= 50 && $height >= 50) {

                           echo "<img src='" . @$images_array[$i] . "' width='400' id='" . $k . "' >";

                           $k++;

                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           ?>
           <input type="hidden" name="total_images" id="total_images" value="<?php echo --$k ?>"/>
       </div>


       <?php
   ```

I will be much gratefull  for your help.thanks

Comment: Use a HTML parser. For PHP, there is DOMDocument.

Comment: @nhahtdh i also want to save the data in  mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = $co->fetch_record ($url2);

$image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$images_array = $img[1];
?>

<div class="images">
    <?php
    $k = 0;
    $area = 0;
    $largest_image;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof ($images_array); $i++) {
        if(@$images_array[$i]) {
            if(@getimagesize (@$images_array[$i])) {
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize (@$images_array[$i]);
                // calculate current image area
                $latest_area = $width * $height;
                // if current image area is greater than previous
                if($latest_area > $area) {
                    $area = $latest_area;
                    $larest_image = $images_array[$i];
                    $k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // at this point the largest image should be in the $largest_image variable
    // print out $largest_image here

    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="total_images" id="total_images" value="<?php echo --$k ?>"/>
</div>


<?php
```